# Ajax operation running later than javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am building a django project which is a website sending form to server and server responds with the queryset just registered by the form and a message string "Create new event successful.".

This is code for it:
`listevent` is another javascript function which shows the queryset the server just received to "sidebar" div. After that, by `document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Create new event successful." );`, appends the message above the result.

**Javascript**

```
function makeEvent(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var year = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(0,4);
            var month = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(5,7);
            var day = event.target.childNodes[3].children[0].value.slice(8,10);
            var form = $("#makeEventForm");
            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);                   
                    listevent(year, month, day);
                    document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Create new event successful." );
                },
                error: function(request,status,error){
                    if (request.status == 599) {
                        listevent(year, month, day);
                        document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Error : time overlaps with another event" );
                    } else {
                        alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+status+"\n"+"error:"+error);
                    }
                },
            });
        }
```

The problem is, when this `makeEvent`function ran and ajax operation successfully done, second line of success function(`listevent(year, month, day);`) seems to run later than third line. As a result, "Create new event successful" does not displayed, because `listevent` function overwrites all contents in `sidebar` div.

So I tried using `setTimeout` on the third line, but it seems like does not work at all time. It'll work if I set the time value sufficiently big, but It looks so bad.

So, my question is:
1. Second line of success function looks like running later than third line, is that right?
2. If so, to third line run after second line ended running, what should I do?

---

## Edit

**listevent function**

```
function listevent(year, month, day){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{% url 'listevent' %}",
                data: {'year':year, 'month':month, 'day':day, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#sidebar").attr('year', year);
                    $("#sidebar").attr('month', month);
                    $("#sidebar").attr('day', day);
                    events = JSON.parse(response.events)
                    var str = "<h4>"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"</h4><br>"
                    if(events.length > 0){
                         events.forEach(event => str += (event['fields']['start_time']+" - "+event['fields']['title']+"<br>"));
                    } else {
                        str += "No events currently."
                    }
                    $("#sidebar").html(str);
                    var btn = $("<button></button>").html("New event");
                    btn.click(function(){
                        makeEventClick(day);
                    });
                    $("#sidebar").append(btn);
                },
                error: function(request,status,error){
                       console.log(error);
                },
            });
        }
```

Comment: Show us what this `listevent` function is actually doing. It sounds like you might have something asynchronously going on in there.

Comment: The above sounds likely, so the quickest fix would be to change `listevent()` so that it appends content rather than overwrites it all

Comment: Added the function, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious because inside `listevent()` you are calling an Async AJAX so it'll run in parallel and obviously will result later than the script response so the script will be executed first, then the ajax response will come and will come into the effect.

To fix you can use `async:false` is the ajax method. This will force the script to wait until the ajax returns response. But this is not a good practice.

```
function listevent(year, month, day){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'listevent' %}",
            async:false, // added
            data: {'year':year, 'month':month, 'day':day, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                $("#sidebar").attr('year', year);
                $("#sidebar").attr('month', month);
                $("#sidebar").attr('day', day);
                events = JSON.parse(response.events)
                var str = "<h4>"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"</h4><br>"
                if(events.length > 0){
                     events.forEach(event => str += (event['fields']['start_time']+" - "+event['fields']['title']+"<br>"));
                } else {
                    str += "No events currently."
                }
                $("#sidebar").html(str);
                var btn = $("<button></button>").html("New event");
                btn.click(function(){
                    makeEventClick(day);
                });
                $("#sidebar").append(btn);
            },
            error: function(request,status,error){
                   console.log(error);
            },
        });
    }
```

---

So as a good practice, you can move the next line inside the `listevent()`.

```
function listevent(year, month, day){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'listevent' %}",
            data: {'year':year, 'month':month, 'day':day, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                $("#sidebar").attr('year', year);
                $("#sidebar").attr('month', month);
                $("#sidebar").attr('day', day);
                events = JSON.parse(response.events)
                var str = "<h4>"+year+"/"+month+"/"+day+"</h4><br>"
                if(events.length > 0){
                     events.forEach(event => str += (event['fields']['start_time']+" - "+event['fields']['title']+"<br>"));
                } else {
                    str += "No events currently."
                }
                $("#sidebar").html(str);
                var btn = $("<button></button>").html("New event");
                btn.click(function(){
                    makeEventClick(day);
                });
                $("#sidebar").append(btn);
                document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Create new event successful." ); // Added
            },
            error: function(request,status,error){
                   console.log(error);
            },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be case of AJAX working out asynchroniosuly. `listevent` is successfully run, but since its AJAX operation the code won't wait until the response is received, that is left of the success/failure callbacks.

So `listevent` is called and AJAX call started and instead of waiting for it to complete, it moves to next line which is `document.getElementById("sidebar").insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', "Create new event successful." );`

So my suggestion would be to move this nside `listevent` at the end of the success callback.